# How to create this array style

Tags: php

Can you help me? Do you know how can I create a array like this style? I want a organized array, meaning the id, title , description, etc...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Fitness News
            [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tincidunt tempor nunc, sit amet facilisis metus molestie nec. Nulla varius justo et felis euismod bibendum. Vestibulum suscipit tempus viverra. Mauris eros lorem, posuere eget mattis et, euismod id metus. In ac dignissim ligula. fdsfdsfdsfds fdsf fsd
            [image1] => test
            [image1_title] => test
            [created] => 2012-03-26
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Recommended Products
            [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tincidunt tempor nunc, sit amet facilisis metus molestie nec. Nulla varius justo et felis euismod bibendum. Vestibulum suscipit tempus viverra. Mauris eros lorem, posuere eget mattis et, euismod id metus. In ac dignissim ligula.gdsfdsfdsfdsfds
            [image1] => H
            [image1_title] => H
            [created] => 2012-03-25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => New Category
            [description] => This is a new category
            [image1] => 
            [image1_title] => 
            [created] => 2012-03-13
        )

)
```

I hope that you understand. Thank you.

Comment: Create an array variable and use `for` loop and in it add an array contain specific values to variable.

Comment: You will have to provide more info on your request.
Usually you get an array while you query a resource (e.g. database, service..) and select the response to associative array or convert the response to an array (e.g. json_decode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use this struct in a loop and fill the child array.

```
$main_array = [];
$main_array[] = array(
           'id'=>'value',
           'title'=>'value',
           'description'=>'value',
           'image1'=>'value',
           'image1_title'=>'value',
           'created'=>'value',
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this array style...

```
$array = array();

$subarr['id'] = 1;
$subarr['title'] = "Fitness News";
$subarr['description'] = "Lorem ipsum dolor";
$subarr['image1'] = "test";
$subarr['image1_title'] = "test";
$subarr['created'] = "2012-03-26";
$array[] = $subarr;

$subarr['id'] = 2;
$subarr['title'] = "Recommended Products";
$subarr['description'] = "Lorem ipsum dolor";
$subarr['image1'] = "test";
$subarr['image1_title'] = "test";
$subarr['created'] = "2012-03-26";
$array[] = $subarr;

.....

$finalarray[] = $array;
```